# Get worker nodes hostname using Terraform

Tags: terraform

How it is possible to get worker nodes hostname using Terraform?

Below is an example of getting all the nodes with a specific label so a solution would be to get all the nodes which have not a specific label (for example, without label node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane) in order to retrieve only worker nodes.

```
data "kubernetes_nodes" "linux" {
  metadata {
    labels = {
      "kubernetes.io/os" = "linux"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which provider is that?

Comment: It's the Kubernetes provider

Comment: While it is possible to determine all of the worker nodes, I do not believe it is possible to return the hostname as a node attribute from the provider according to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, a workaround was to list the control-plane nodes and to remove this list from the list of all the linux nodes.

```
data "kubernetes_nodes" "linux" {
  metadata {
    labels = {
      "kubernetes.io/os" = "linux"
    }
  }
}

data "kubernetes_nodes" "control-plane" {
  metadata {
    labels = {
      "kubernetes.io/os" = "linux"
      "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane" = ""
    }
  }
}

locals {
  worker_nodes = toset([for node in data.kubernetes_nodes.linux.nodes : node.metadata.0.name if !contains(data.kubernetes_nodes.control-plane.nodes, node)])
}
```